# Laravel 5.2 saving images into public folder

Tags: php, laravel, file-upload, laravel-5

**EDIT**

I am trying to do a form, when you will select and upload image. Then I want to save this image to public folder in my project (for example: project/public/images). I am getting this error:

```
ReflectionException in Route.php line 280:
Class App\Http\Controllers\ImageUploadRequest does not exist
```

My HomeController:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Article;
use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Requests\ImageUploadRequest;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;

class HomeController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }
public function uploadImage(ImageUploadRequest $request) {
        if (Auth::check()) {
            if (Auth::user()->admin == 1) {
                $image = $request->file('file');
                //$filename  = time()."-".$image->getClientOriginalName();
                $image->move(public_path("/uploads"), "test");
                //$file = Image::make(sprintf('uploads/%s', "ahoj"))->resize(600,400)->save();
                return view('admin.uploadImage');
            }
            return view('/');
        }
        return view('/');
    }
```

ImageUploadRequest:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Requests;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;

abstract class ImageUploadRequest extends FormRequest
{
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'file' => 'required'
        ];
    }
}
```

Routes.php:

```
Route::post('uploadImage', [
        'as' => 'uploadImage',
        'uses' => 'ImageUploadRequest@rules'
    ]);
```

My form:

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')

<form name="upload_image" method="post" action="{{route('uploadImage')}}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" accept="image/*" name="file">
    <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
    <input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
{{$path = "ahoj"}}
            <p>{{$path}}</p>
@endsection
```

Comment: Error: http://pastebin.com/4GbRjETs

Comment: I have edited your question appending the error of your comment. Consider do it yourself next times to keep centralized information for the rest of users.

Answer (score 3):

Try this route instead:

```
Route::post('uploadImage', [
    'as' => 'uploadImage',
    'uses' => 'HomeController@uploadImage'
]);
```

You was calling the request instead controller.

Comment: Pretty sure this is the answer.

Comment: Thank you! It seems better, I`m not getting any error now, but it says "forbidden" :(

Answer (score 0):

You forgot the `enctype="multipart/form-data"` in the form

Comment: Thank you, I editted it and now i am getting this error: ReflectionException in Route.php line 280:
Class App\Http\Controllers\ImageUploadRequest does not exist

Comment: @xtrontross, you need to import the class: `use App\Http\Requests\ImageUploadRequest;` in the controller

Comment: Edit your question and include the content of your controller.

Comment: I see.. remove "abstract" from ImageUploadRequest class declaration and try again